# Android - Avoid memory leaks for images extracted from Gallery

Tags: android, android-layout, android-intent, android-emulator, android-widget

I need to let the user open a specific album from their gallery, and let them to do something with images.

In order to retrieve an image from an album, I'm using:
`Bitmap bitmap = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(contentResolver, uri).`

Everything works fine, except the fact that if the album contains many pictures, it ends up trowing an `OutOfMemoryException.`
Now, I know how to mitigate this issue based on [Android guidelines](http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/index.html), but the problem is that I'm already retrieving the original Bitmap with `getBitmap()`

So, is there a possibility to retrieve the image in the byte array format, or an input stream format, and scale it down before assigning it in memory to avoid memory leaks? (in the same way the Android guidelines advice)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, having a image `Uri` in my hands I wanted to retrieve it's `InputStream` and scale down the image before assigning it in memory to avoid `OutOfMemoryException`

**Solution:**
To retrieve the InputStream from an Uri, you have to call this:

```
InputStream stream = getContentResolver().openInputStream(uri);
```

Then following Android recommendations on [loading bitmaps efficiently](http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/load-bitmap.html), you just need to call `BitmapFactory.decodeStream()`, and pass the `BitmapFactory.Options` as a parameter.

**Full source code:**

```
imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView);

Uri uri = Uri.parse("android.resource://com.testcontentproviders/drawable/"+R.drawable.test_image_large);
Bitmap bitmap=null;
    try {
        InputStream stream = getContentResolver().openInputStream(uri);
        bitmap=decodeSampledBitmapFromStream(stream, 150, 100);
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
```

Helper methods:

```
public static Bitmap decodeSampledBitmapFromStream(InputStream stream,
            int reqWidth, int reqHeight) {

    // First decode with inJustDecodeBounds=true to check dimensions
    final BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
    options.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
    BitmapFactory.decodeStream(stream, null, options);

    // Calculate inSampleSize
    options.inSampleSize = calculateInSampleSize(options, reqWidth,
                reqHeight);

    // Decode bitmap with inSampleSize set
    options.inJustDecodeBounds = false;
    return BitmapFactory.decodeStream(stream, null, options);
}

public static int calculateInSampleSize(BitmapFactory.Options options,
            int reqWidth, int reqHeight) {
    // Raw height and width of image
    final int height = options.outHeight;
    final int width = options.outWidth;
    int inSampleSize = 1;

    if (height > reqHeight || width > reqWidth) {
        if (width > height) {
            inSampleSize = Math.round((float) height / (float) reqHeight);
        } else {
            inSampleSize = Math.round((float) width / (float) reqWidth);
        }
    }
    return inSampleSize;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You've already identified a very good solution.  If you want to skip the step of pulling the image into a `Bitmap` via the `MediaStore`, try using [ImageView.setImageUri()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageView.html#setImageURI%28android.net.Uri%29).

Comment: Hi, thank you for the comment. Trying to pass the Uri to the ImageView before scaling also is causing OutOfMemoryException it the image is too big. But you opened up a new alternative for me, and based on that image Uri now I'm able to retrieve the InputStream and scale down the image. I'll post the solution soon.